# connecting to my APP from other local computer or phone. Angular and MongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb

I am trying to display my app in other devices, but something is not working with my Database, i am running my app with angular 6 CLI, this is the command that i use

> ( ng serve --host 192.168.0.15 ) // Running in port 4200

i am using mongodb with express and mongoose, my server is running in localhost:4000.

So if i use my mobile phone and type 192.168.0.15:4200 works...but the db is not working...
 // Everything works in my local computer.

I think i have to configure the db... out of localhost:4000, something like 192.168.0.15:4000... how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

> I am not sure, but it should work

Comment: i did something new, in my API Rest i created a new route, localhost:4000/api...

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json('Helloo')
})

when i access with my phone, to this adress 192.168.0.15:4000/api i receive this "Hello"..... sooo what the hell....???

Comment: so it means that the server is working from other device... but i cant understand why my login does not work... i am going to edit the question